# m³/s in C# is show as m&#179;/s in HTML

Tags: c#, html

I´m writing a program that shows a diagram with several curves showing some data of a machine. The code is in C#, JavaScript, CSS and HTML.
Now my problem is that I want to have a title for my x-axis. It should show [m³/s], but instead it shows `[m&#179;/s]`. The [m³/s] is written in C#. Seems that the ³ is transformed into ASCII-Code.
Is there any way to show it as expected?

Comment: Please can you share the code where you populate / display the character?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. We'd need to see the relevant code to verify, though.

Answer (score 1):

If the html is itself UTF-8 encoded, then `m³/s` should work as-is - which you can see via "view source" on this page, and looking for `/s]` (and looking back a few characters, obviously) - you'll see that it isn't explicitly encoded; if not, `m&#xB3;/s` should work reliably as an alternative; `m&sup3;/s` is also a possibility, although it might not work on older browsers.